# React JS Sortable Form Fields as Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I'm trying to develop a fairly simplistic E-Mail template creator with React JS. I'm using the "react-sortable-hoc" library as a means to handle the ordering of elements on the page.

The goal is to allow users to create "Rows", rearrange rows, and within each row, have multiple "Columns" that can contain components like images, textboxes, etc...

But I keep running into the same issue with Sortable libraries. Form fields cannot maintain their own "state" when being dragged up or down. The State of a Component in React JS seems to be lost when it's in a draggable component. I've experienced similar issues with JQuery UI's Sortable but it required an equally ridiculous solution. Is it common to find that form fields are simply super difficult to rearrange?

As a "proof of concept", I am using a complex JSON object that stores all the information in the Letter.js component and passes it down as Props which are then passed down to each component. But as you can tell, this is becoming cumbersome.

Here is an example of my Letter component that handles the JSON object and sorting of Rows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {
  SortableContainer, 
  SortableElement, 
  arrayMove
} from 'react-sortable-hoc';
import Row from './Row';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({row, rowIndex, onChange, addPart}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Row 
        row={row} 
        rowIndex={rowIndex} 
        onChange={onChange}
        addPart={addPart} />
    </li>
  )
});

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({rows, onChange, addPart}) => {
  return (
    <ul id="sortableList">
      {rows.map((row, index) => {
        return (
          <SortableItem
            key={`row-${index}`} 
            index={index} 
            row={row}
            rowIndex={index}
            onChange={onChange}
            addPart={addPart}
           /> )
      })}
    </ul>
  );
});

class Letter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: [],
    }

    this.onSortEnd    = this.onSortEnd.bind(this);
    this.onChange     = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.addRow       = this.addRow.bind(this);
    this.addPart      = this.addPart.bind(this);
  }

  addPart(event, index, value, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
    console.log(value);
    var part = {};
    if(value === 'Text') {
      part = {
        type: 'Text',
        value: ''
      }
    } else if(value === 'Image') {
      part = {
        type: 'Image',
        value: ''
      }
    } else {
      part = {
        type: 'Empty',
      }
    }
    const { rows  } = this.state;
    rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = part;
    this.setState({ rows: rows })
  }

  onChange(text, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[rowIndex][columnIndex].value = text;
    this.setState({ rows: newRows });
  }

  addRow(columnCount) {
    var rows = this.state.rows.slice();
    var row = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
      var part = {
        type: 'Empty',
      }
      row.push(part);
    }
    rows.push(row);
    this.setState({ rows: rows })
  }

  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
      rows: arrayMove(this.state.rows, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.rows));
    const SideBar = (
      <div className="sideBar">
        <h3>Add a Row</h3>
        <button className="uw-button" onClick={() => this.addRow(1)}>1 - Column</button><br/><br/>
        <button className="uw-button" onClick={() => this.addRow(2)}>2 - Column</button><br/><br/>
        <button className="uw-button" onClick={() => this.addRow(3)}>3 - Column</button>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );

    if(this.state.rows.length <= 0) {
      return (
        <div className="grid">
          <p>This E-Mail is currently empty! Add some components to make a template.</p>
          {SideBar}
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        <SortableList 
          rows={this.state.rows} 
          onChange={this.onChange}
          addPart={this.addPart}
          lockAxis="y"
          useDragHandle={true}
          onSortStart={this.onSortStart} 
          onSortMove={this.onSortMove}
          onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} 
          shouldCancelStart={this.shouldCancelStart} />
        {SideBar}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Letter;
```

And here is an example of Row:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Image } from './components/';

import { SortableHandle } from 'react-sortable-hoc';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardMedia, CardTitle, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';


const DragHandle = SortableHandle(() => <span className="dragHandle"></span>);


class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.row !== undefined && this.props.row.length > 0) {
      const row = this.props.row.map((column, columnIndex) => {
        if(column.type === 'Empty') {
          return (
            <MuiThemeProvider key={columnIndex}>
              <div className="emptyColumn">
                <Card>
                  <DragHandle />
                  <CardTitle title="Empty Component"/>
                  <DropDownMenu value={"Empty"} onChange={(event, index, value) => this.props.addPart(event, index, value, this.props.rowIndex, columnIndex)}>
                    <MenuItem value={"Empty"} primaryText="Empty" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Text"} primaryText="Textbox" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Image"} primaryText="Image" />
                  </DropDownMenu>
                </Card>
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          )
        } else if(column.type === 'Text') {
           return (
            <MuiThemeProvider key={columnIndex}>
              <div className="textColumn">
                <Card>
                  <DragHandle />
                  <CardTitle title="Textbox"/>
                  <DropDownMenu value={"Text"} onChange={(event, index, value) => this.props.addPart(event, index, value, this.props.rowIndex, columnIndex)}>
                    <MenuItem value={"Empty"} primaryText="Empty" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Text"} primaryText="Textbox" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Image"} primaryText="Image" />
                  </DropDownMenu>
                  <Text 
                    value={this.props.row[columnIndex].value} 
                    onChange={this.props.onChange} 
                    columnIndex={columnIndex}
                    rowIndex={this.props.rowIndex} />
                </Card>
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          )         
        } else if(column.type === 'Image') {
           return (
            <MuiThemeProvider key={columnIndex}>
              <div className="textColumn">
                <Card>
                  <DragHandle />
                  <CardTitle title="Image"/>
                  <DropDownMenu value={"Image"} onChange={(event, index, value) => this.props.addPart(event, index, value, this.props.rowIndex, columnIndex)}>
                    <MenuItem value={"Empty"} primaryText="Empty" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Text"} primaryText="Textbox" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Image"} primaryText="Image" />
                  </DropDownMenu>
                  <Image 
                    columnIndex={columnIndex}
                    rowIndex={this.props.rowIndex} />
                </Card>
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          )         
        }
      })


      return (
        <div className="row">
          {row}
        </div>
      )
    }

    return <p>No components</p>;

  }
}

export default Row;
```

Lastly, this is what Text.js looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'; 

class Text extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactQuill value={this.props.value}
                  onChange={(text) => this.props.onChange(text, this.props.rowIndex, this.props.columnIndex)} />
    )
  }
}

export default Text;
```

So, I keep having to pass ridiculous parameters to onChange functions and other functions in order to ensure that the state is maintained while sorting and editing. So, how should I be handling this? I don't want **Letter.js** (which is basically App.js) to handle all of my data handling. I want each *component* to handle it's own. I want Text.js to handle the onChange effects of its text. But I just can't see a way around passing everything down as props.

Comment: Time to introduce a store such as redux/mobx. Store the data in the store. connect to the store in individual components. create actions to do operations on the data.

Comment: Okay, I'll research Redux / Mobx I've seen a little bit regarding Redux, but not enough to really understand it.

Comment: Nothing complicated, think of it like a object store in the memory. Which is also immutable. here is a short intro  https://medium.com/@christiannaths/from-zero-to-redux-8db779b6ed01